# Will a mysql restart flush the hosts cache (like FLUSH HOSTS)?

Tags: mysql, caching

I'm getting "'host_name' is blocked because of many connection errors".  I know the reason for the failed connections, and the cause is resolved.

To reset the condition, I assume that FLUSH HOSTS needs to be run at the *remote* host, but I don't have sufficient (RELOAD) privilege there.

If mysql is (ever) restarted on the remote host, will the hosts cache be cleared?  (as if a FLUSH HOSTS had been run)

Otherwise, will the condition persist for some period of time? Or for ever?

Answer (score 0):

I can not find documentation that the information in the host cache is cleared on MySQL restart.

I have been able to get an answer in practice with MySQL 5.5...

- force a host to reach max_connect_errors (telnet hostname 3306 repeatedly until it fails)
- verify MySQL client connections would fail with ERROR 1129 (HY000): Host '$hostname' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
- restart MySQL
- successfully connect with MySQL client after the restart.